# Lenovo IdeaPad A1 Tablet - External keyboard

Tags: keyboard, lenovo-laptop

I'm trying to get [an external keyboard](http://www.ebay.de/itm/110948136129?ssPageName=STRK:MEWNX:IT&_trksid=p3984.m1497.l2649) to work with a [Lenovo IdeaPad A1](http://www.lenovo.com/products/us/tablet/ideapad/a1/) tablet. It's connected through an OTG *USB to Micro USB* cable. 
The tablet seems not to recognize the keyboard input. (The keyboard works well with my PC)

Do I need to enable some settings or download some kind of app or driver to make it work?
Any ideas welcome.

**Edit:** Could it be possible that the keyboard doesn't get enough power from the tablet to work?

Answer (score 1):

Please try to press and hold the text bar (where you would normally input text). This should bring up a prompt so you can then click on input method.

Comment: The external keyboard still doesn't gets recognized.

Comment: And do you know if the keyboard is working correctly? Can you plug it into a PC or Laptop?

Comment: Also, the keyboard you got is USB - the USB addpater on your tablet (according to the link you sent) is Mini USB. Is this correct?

Comment: The keyboard works fine on my laptop. The USB adapter is USB to **Micro** USB and plugs into the tablet.

Comment: Because it's a micro USB on the tablet it implies it's not going to accept the keyboard. A lot of A1 users have issues with the USB keyboards, as the A1 doesn't seem to support USB host mode/USB OTG, meaning that no device can be connected to and work with A1 using the usb port (see comments about usb keyboard suggested by Amazon.co.uk to be bought with A1). Some say that there may be a workaround for that using a special usb cable, some others that USB OTG. IMO sell it off and get a bluetooth keyboard.